# Do I need NiMH discharge protection when load is only LEDs

Tags: led, protection, nimh, over-discharge

I'm powering a bunch of LEDs using 3 NiMH cells in series. I don't think I need worry about deep discharge protection as the LEDs will switch off when the voltage drops below their forward voltage.

The LEDs are the colour cycling type and their datasheet gives Vf of between 3.2 and 3.6 volts.

Thanks for any help :)

Comment: Are you going to leave the batteries hooked up for a long period of time once the LEDs go out? If so, beware of the (small) current that still flows below the forward voltage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just wire it up and see what happens. If the forward current drops to less than 10uA somewhere above 2V or so then it should be OK. Those numbers are not hard and fast. But you do want the current to drop to something like 10uA or less before the cells get severely discharged. You can test it with a power supply and a uA meter or just put a volt meter across the resistor and use Ohm's law to calculate the current. Measure the voltage at which If is 10uA. Or better yet, measure the current at 3V, 2.9V, 2.8V and so on down to 2V then come back and answer your own question with a nice graph of the result.

With a little work, and knowing the battery discharge curve, you can estimate how long it will take to get from 3V to 2V, and that will tell you whether it is reasonably safe or whether you need a low-voltage cutoff.

One thing that concerns me is that it sounds like you want to drive your LED's at 3.2 or 3.6 V but you only have three NiMH batteries in series. Normally, to drive LEDs, you need some headroom above and beyond the Vf of the LED. If you need 3.6V, then three LED's in series is not going to work without a boost converter. Even 3.2 is iffy.

So you may need to bump it up to 4 NiMH in series, and in that case you are more likely to need the low-voltage cutoff. Either way I would definitely characterize the current vs voltage of the load so you can make a more informed decision about all of this.

Comment: I found in another question / answer here on StackExchange that 0.9V for a NiMH cell is the safe discharge voltage, 0.8V at a push.
I can see I wasn't clear in my question - the LEDs are in parallel, not series, so a Vf of 3.6 is fine.
I do need a low-voltage cutoff - the measured current when the 3 NiMH in series had dropped to 2.4V was 46mA so driving a cut-off MOSFET does make sense.
Thanks for helping me see this :)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you need discharge protection if you need to prevent batteries from discharging to too low voltage.

LEDs have the rated forward voltage at rated forward current.

Which means that they do light up and consume current below the rated forward voltage, but they will also consume less current.

Comment: I mean, yeah, but even with 10uA the LED will have a substantial forward voltage. Cutoff circuits also consume a small amount of current. So OP should characterize the IV curve of the circuit and then decide if a cutoff is needed. If the load current is 10uA at the point where the cutoff would normally operate, and the cutoff also consumes 10uA then there is not much point in adding the cutoff circuit.

Comment: Thanks, that encouraged me to to do some digging. I found that if the forward voltage across each LED dropped a little below 1 volt, then the LED current would be negligible. Of course, 1V is way too low for 3 NiMH in series so I do need some form of discharge protection.